# Chassis / case for electronics projects

Tags: interconnect

I'm looking for some chassis and cases to put my electronics projects in. My projects tend to involve at least one microcontroller and/or fpga. My boards are often very "verbose" and I put few major features on each board so I often end up with several boards. I would like an easy way to both reuse some of the boards across projects but also have a structured way to connect the boards, not just lay them out on my desk as I do now.

I would like something like this [image: http://www.errock.co.uk/motherboard%20rack%20photo%20high%20res.jpg] except that it shouldn't cost me my first born. It doesn't have to be as big, but I would like something that can hold a handful of boards and have a "useful" backboard. It would be nice if uses standard VME connectors or something similar (even ISA would be useful). Hopefully each board be 100mmx160mm in size, but that's not critical either.

Also, does anyone have an alternate way of organizing the few boards that make up a project?

Comment: I'm having a hard time picturing your different boards, because it sounds like they'd all have different form factors, but you also mention a backplane.  Can you update your post with a pic?

Comment: When I'm making my own boards I only use 160mm x 100mm prototyping boards. I can also get boards of the same size that I can etch myself. This is one possible board https://www.elfa.se/elfa3~no_no/elfa/init.do?item=48-504-20&toc=20548, it even has place for a connector at the end.

Comment: The other boards I'm buying are usually smaller than 160x100 so I can just mount them on a board and use the bigger board to connect the back plane and connections on the smaller board.

Comment: A case + backplane like this is something like what I'm after: http://www.s100computers.com/My%20System%20Index%20Page.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Design your own Eurocard motherboard PCB using DIN41612 connectors that will fit in a standard low-cost enclosure like [this](http://www.rapidonline.com/sku/Tools-Fasteners-Production-Equipment/Enclosures/Metal-Cases/Steel-cases/62620/30-0240) one. That should hold half-length Eurocards (100 mm x 80 mm).

Comment: Got an example of a low-cost enclosure? I wouldn't mind paying for a decent backboard just for not having to spend timing designing *another* part and make sure it'll fit in the enclosure.

Answer (score 1):

You can design a custom enclosure to fit your boards and have [Ponoko](http://www.ponoko.com/) make it.  I think it's pretty cheap.

[Making Enclosures for Electronics with Ponoko](http://blog.ponoko.com/2010/10/25/making-enclosures-for-electronics-with-ponoko/)

Answer (score 1):

This is another option: http://buckeyeshapeform.thomasnet.com/item/bmx-bmu-rackmount-desktop-enclosures/bmu-series-cases/bmu-10-100-13.

They look very 1980s, but they.